# Add image of Button to any Picture Box

Tags: c#

In my form load, there is a button and picture box. I added a image to my button(from backgroundimage) and When I click this button, the image is also added to Picture Box. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the Image property on the picturebox to the Button's Image property in the click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = button1.Image;
}
```

EDIT: Or the BackgroundImage property:

```
pictureBox1.Image = button1.BackgroundImage;
```